# Injecting multiple files into bookmarklets

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

At the moment, I am using the code from here: http://benalman.com/projects/run-jquery-code-bookmarklet/ to write bookmarklets with jQuery. Now, jQuery isn't enough and i want to include other libraries/css files, but it isn't the prettiest with this example. Is there a framework for creating bookmarklets available anywhere?

What is the best way to go about creating bookmarklets with the ability to inject multiple scripts/files? Any better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a framework for creating bookmarklets available anywhere?

Short: Probably not.

Long: It is not really possible to say "no" and be sure, because rarely can anyone know everything about a subject. I *can* say that I keep an eye on the subject of bookmarklets (you'll see that most of my SO answers are related), and I've not yet seen such a thing. I could start to imagine how one might be created, but - depending on your goals - I doubt the effort wold be worthwhile.

> What is the best way to go about creating bookmarklets with the ability to inject multiple scripts/files?

Well, no matter what, you probably need to load things sequentially, which requires using onload or similar state change events to trigger next steps. Depending on goals, you might load all files sequentially or async or some combination. There are probably a number of solutions for this, but it depends on your needs and aesthetic sensibilities as to which is suitable. I'd start with a Google search for `javascript lazy load js files`.